# Parse a complex string into into separate Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, parsing

I need to parse a string with varying field lengths into separate columns.
I have the following series of data.

[image]

Using Formulas I would like to Populate columns F, G, H and I the the various field sections in Column D. I have created the current content manually but would like to do this with formulas.

I can get most of it correct but am having trouble with Column G because this data sometimes has two characters (i.e. 01, 03) and sometimes has five characters (i.e. 01-16).

Comment: You want to always break on the space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a straight forward way to do it assuming format stays something [space] something [space] etc.  The trick is to focus on the spaces (delimiters) and not on the data (text)

- column F =left($d6,find(" ",$d6))
  this uses a find to figure out how much to pull.
- Column g =MID($D6,1+LEN(F6),FIND(" ",$D6,1+LEN(F6))-LEN(F6))

This uses a mid with starting after column f, and then looking for the second space

- Column h =MID($D6,1+LEN(F6&G6),FIND(" ",$D6,1+LEN(F6&G6))-1-LEN(F6&G6))

This follows the same pattern. Use a mid and start past the previous 2 columns of data, look for the next space, and the difference is how much to use.

Just copy it down.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! 
I really struggle with nested formulas and your solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel go to *Text to Columns*
[image]

select *Delimited*:

[image]

select *Space*:

[image]

Clcik Next and you'll have it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Text to Columns method, but since you asked for a formula, put this in B2 copy over and down:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2," ",REPT(" ",999)),(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*999+1,999))
```

[image]

Comment: Now that's using your head!